# OpenGL can only bind to GL_TEXTURE0

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader

I'm trying to bind multiple textures to my shader but when I use some other enum than `GL_TEXTURE0` my shader shows unpredictable behaviour (e.g. all inout variables get zero).
This is how I bind the textures (in other projects this works prefectly)

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
sceneTex->bind();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
depthTex->bind();

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
VBO->bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
unsigned int stride = 2 * sizeof(float) + 2 * sizeof(float);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
VBO->unbind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
sceneTex->unbind();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
depthTex->unbind();
```

When I remove `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)` everything works fine. When I remove `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` I still get the problem. The same problem occurs if I try to use `GL_TEXTURE2` or some other enum.

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 440

out vec4 fragColor;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D colorMap;
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D depthMap;

in vec2 texUV;

void main()
{
    fragColor = texture(colorMap, texUV) / 2.0 + texture(depthMap, texUV) / 2.0;
}
```

When I check the states with `glGetIntegerv` everything seems fine. But it isn't.

Comment: Can you show a shader that actually samples those textures? RIght now you have two unused uniforms in your fragment shader.

Comment: Yeah, but this i enough to crash everything. If i use the textures like fragColor = texture(colorMap, texUV) nothing changes.

Comment: Why did this question got downvoted? I changed the fragment shader so it uses the textures. But as I said the problem stays the same and the behaviour is unpredictable (right now texUV is (0,0) and fragColor.a is everytime another value when starting my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the error and I have to commit that I made a real beginner mistake. Hard to believe that no one found this error.
I thought that one call of `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` would be enough for all texture slots but how i found it you have to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` for every active texture you have. So the right code looks like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
sceneTex->bind();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
depthTex->bind();

// draw some stuff

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
sceneTex->unbind();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
depthTex->unbind();
```

Comment: There's something very odd going on here. `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` has no effect if sampling is done from a shader. It is a (deprecated) call used to control fixed function rendering. And your question suggests that you sample the textures from a fragment shader. So this should not make a difference at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I use a proprietary framework so I don't have more detailed infos. But I know that the compatibility profile is used. Maybe this is the reason?